# universal abelian covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $X$ be a path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected topological space. (Let $(Y,p)$ be a covering space of $X$, then it is called an **abelian covering space** if it is normal and its automorphism group as a $X$-covering space is abelian. It's called a **universal abelian covering space** if it is abelian and for any abelian covering space $(Z,q)$ of $X$, there is division $r$, such that $p =rq$.) Prove that $X$ has a universal abelian covering space, and it's unique up to isomorphism. **Construct an abelian universal covering space for $S^1 \vee S^1$**.

Since $X$ is path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected, it has a universal covering space. Does the existence of a universal covering space have something to do with the existence of a universal abelian covering space? Moreover, the uniqueness part does not seem to be easy for me... Let $(Y_1,p_1)$ and $(Y_2,p_2)$ be two universal abelian coverings of $X$, then by definition, there exist $r_1:: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ and $r_2:Y_2 \rightarrow Y_1$ such that $p_1 = p_2 \cdot r_1$ and $p_2 = p_1 \cdot r_2$. Then are $r_1$ and $r_2$ isomorphisms and inverses to each other?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The universal abelian covering space corresponds to the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group.

Comment: @Jim Belk: Thanks for the comment. So I can use the classification theorem of covering spaces directly to explain the existence and uniqueness of universal abelian covering? But how can I do the construction for $S^1 \vee S^1$? Thanks.

Comment: The fundamental group of the wedge of two circles is free on two generators. What is its abelianization (i.e., free abelian group on two generators)?

Comment: @Jim Belk: Thanks very much. As long as I know the group corresponding to this covering (its automorphism group as covering space), how can I construct it?